# wsdl2java and document/literal wrapped style issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl2java

Everybody, Hello!

Say, I have a web-service:

```
@WebService
public interface StubWebService {
   /**
    * Just a stub method.
    */
   public void stubMethod();

}
```

And I want to generate a client of it with the wsdl2java tool. After the generation I get a document/literal wrapped web-service stub. Let's look on it:

```
    @WebService(targetNamespace = "target", name =    
         "StubWebService")
    @XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
    public interface StubWebService {

      @RequestWrapper(
        localName = "stubMethod",
        targetNamespace = "target",
        className = "packageName.StubMethod")
      @WebMethod
      @ResponseWrapper(
        localName = "stubMethodResponse",
        targetNamespace = "target",
        className = "packageName.StubMethodResponse")
      public void stubMethod();
   }
```

and, of course:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "stubMethod")
public class StubMethod {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "stubMethodResponse")
public class StubMethodResponse {
}
```

As one can see there are duplicate fragments, for example :

```
@RequestWrapper(localName = "stubMethod"
```

and

```
 @XmlType(name = "stubMethod")
```

Because of it the exception "IllegalAnnotationException: Two classes have the same XML type..." raises. The solution is to change the @XmlType(name= on something other than "stubMethod", say "stubMethod1".

My question is, why the wsdl2java tool generates the apriory broken code and what is the 'internal' schema, the @XmlType produce a binding to (where the "stubMethod1" tag is presented)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it complains only about stubMethod? no complains about stubMethodResponse?

Comment: The behavior is the same fro the stubMethodResponse...

Comment: Actually, it is the same for each wrapper class.